# Google Compute Engine Copy Files

Tags: google-compute-engine, file-copying, gcloud

I would like to copy files from my local mac to gcloud. I have been using the SSH terminal provided in the VM instance, which opens as another browser instance. I use the command of

```
gcloud compute copy-files /Users/jayanth/Downloads/init.txt killbill:/home/jayanth_gmail/killbill --zone 'asia-east1-a'
```

however I get the error of

```
/Users/jayanth/Downloads/init.txt: No such file or directory
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.copy-files) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].
```

Please help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running gcloud within an ssh terminal, it won't be able to see files on your local file system (eg /Users/jayanth/Downloads/init.txt). To copy that file, you'll need to install the Cloud SDK on your mac and run it locally.